# Wifi disconnects and is unable to detect networks

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager

I run Ubuntu 19.04, and recently I've been unable to connect to WiFi. Upon startup it will detect the available networks, but then changes to showing no networks available. I'm currently dual-booting with Windows 10, which has no such problems, so I don't believe it's an issue with the WiFi network itself.

When the problem first appeared I could often solve it by booting up Windows, then restarting and using Ubuntu, but that doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated.

```
$ iwconfig
docker0   no wireless extensions.

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ dmesg | grep wlp2s0
[    3.659184] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.550927] wlp2s0: authenticate with 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81
[    8.564258] wlp2s0: send auth to 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81 (try 1/3)
[    8.571202] wlp2s0: authenticated
[    8.575167] wlp2s0: associate with 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81 (try 1/3)
[    8.577793] wlp2s0: RX AssocResp from 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=1)
[    8.579689] wlp2s0: associated
[    8.612308] wlp2s0: Limiting TX power to 36 (36 - 0) dBm as advertised by 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81
[    8.831503] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
[   19.089777] p2p-dev-wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x0
[   19.089931] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   19.089934] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.090299] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.090516] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.090706] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.090941] wlp2s0: HW problem - can not stop rx aggregation for 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81 tid 0
[   19.090954] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.091597] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.091916] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.092131] wlp2s0: failed to remove key (0, 38:17:c3:8b:c2:81) from hardware (-5)
[   19.092153] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.092526] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.092884] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093104] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093285] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093462] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093639] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093816] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.093992] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.094181] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.094838] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[   19.095179] wlp2s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-5)
[   19.095427] wlp2s0:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
```

```
$ sudo rfkill list && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 [8086:0010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I booted from a USB with 18.04.3 and suffered the same issue. All wireless networks were briefly visible, and then after a short period (15-20 seconds) they disappeared and the Network Manager said there were no visible networks.

Comment: Please run `sudo rfkill list && lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and post the results into your question with [edit]. Also advise there what happens when you boot from a LiveUSB of 18.04.3 and try connecting. Please don't use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit].  Editing & formatting tips are at http://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code